# Smoke in view port not always showing

Tags: 3d-view, smoke-simulation

**Blender Ver 2.77a**
hp elitebook 8460p
i5 2520m
Intel HD 3000 (crap) graphics
16GB RAM

I'm just starting Blender.

When I set up a smoke domain using a half a **Sphere**, and the **Quick Smoke** (the long way of doing this too, using youtube how tos).

When I run it <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it will show the smoke, then every time after that it is gets worse and then begins not showing smoke, so I have no way of knowing my results unless I render it to a file then check it like that.

Problem two, it sticks on frame 1 at times as well after following the youtube video I go to play it again to see the results, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and it cycles frame 1.

I wish, I knew what detailed information you really needed to understand what I am talking about, but I am confused about this so me making heads or tails out of it to enplane it in here better is a far cry to do.

Comment: You should post your [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, I found that Blender's Cycles render engine is not compatible with the Intel HD 3000 (waste of time developing it) graphics "card" on my laptop. I purchased a new (different, used) motherboard with an ATI graphics  card for 25$ cheap...hopefully that will fix this issue.

Comment: Ati graphic card have other compatibility issues when using cycles...